# Asus P8Z68-V LX - Memory problems

Tags: ddr3, intel-core-i5, ivy-bridge

I just bought a new CPU and a motherboard yesterday. after stuffing it all together and for the first time booting it, it just went looping to starting on and off. I figured that this was something about the memory...

eventually I got it working with a Corsair XMS3 - 1600 HMZ 2x6 GB .. however when it finally shows how much memory I had, it just show 2gb, and running at 1333mhz, I know this motherboard supports 1600 MHZ and plenty of memory.

so 1333mhz is ok for me, but the amount of ram is not, I tried to put another same and i get 4 gb... I also have some kingston memory at 2x4 gb I put in, and they also only show up as 2 gb...

Upgrading the bios did not do anything new...

totally I should have about 20gb of memory with these inserted

so how am I going to make it find the memory correctly?

any manual settings I can do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your Manual which you can [download from Asus](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8Z68V_LX/#download) there are no settings in the BIOS which would limit the amount of memory the system recognizes.  I'm sure if you went into the Tweaker section, you could manually alter settings that would make the system NOT recognize your memory... but simply loading the defaults (by the Load Defaults button on the first page of the BIOS) would remove any of those settings.  And yeah, it supports 32gb of 2200mhz DDR3 Ram.

You didn't go messing about with changing those settings, did you?  I mean, you didn't say that you did.  You *did* hit the Load Defaults, just to clear the BIOS back to the default state, right?

Well, if loading the defaults doesn't do it, I'd RMA the board.

Comment: hi!, thanks for an answer, I have been looking around under the AE tweaking, but could not find anything special there, i have no honest clue why only 2 gb is usable per ram module. i also try to set everything to auto.

Comment: I will investigate this further, if the ram modules really is what they are, or if someone have been playing funnny, sticking another memory label on them... http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/262/minne.png

Comment: board was OK!, i had seen wrong, the memory says 6x2gb that means this was a kit of 6x XMS memory modules... and I had only 2, which will give 4 gig of memory, same applied to the kingston memory :)

sorry for the confusion, but thank you for the insight :)

Comment: see, this is why diagnosing problems based on what people type into a Q&A based website is difficult.  Sometimes the information people include is just wrong.  Glad you got it sorted out though.